# To Get DataDirectory Path in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have Access Database in \bin\debug..I am creating one utility to take Backup.So that I need to get the path of database..After that i will copy that file from that location to other  location..So plz help me to get path.

Comment: it's would be easier if you put your DB in another place and you assign if fullpath when you create db connection ..

Comment: Why ? otherwise what happened ?

Comment: Nothing will happen .. But I think, it will be easier if you put your DB in same folder with your EXE, then you will just need `application.startuppath` .. beside, you will no longer have folder `\bin\debug` after deployment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 path = Application.StartupPath & "\creation.mdb" 
 If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path) 
 Then 
   MessageBox.Show("File is available") 
 Else 
   MessageBox.Show("File is Not available") 
 End If
```

I tried and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set in your database property to replace on each build .. so you will get fresh copy of your database while each build/deploy of your project at your bin directory using

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Comment: Dear Satish, that was not my question. That is the automatic function using database App but I wanted to take backup of that database using application.

Comment: Dear Techno Cracker.. Through that you can take your database backup. :)

Answer (score 2):

`My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`

Gives you the directory where the startup exe is located

Comment: After Deploy the \bin\debug folder will be same ??

Comment: it wont be *the same* but where ever the product is installed, `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` will point to it.

Answer (score 1):

> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

gives you the name of the directory where your application has been started.

Code:

```
Dim databasePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "creation.mdb")
```

Comment: After Deploy the \bin\debug folder will be same ??

Comment: Yes, and if you compile in release it would be `\bin\release`.

Comment: Can you tell me How to take database file to that path ?
I mean my database file is "\bin\debug\creation.mdb".How can i get full file path ??plz tell me

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I assigned that path into string and displayed it...But it is showing "Database Current Path"..How can i get that actual path which inclusive "\" also..Ex. "C:\program files\"

Comment: `path = Application.StartupPath & "\creation.mdb"
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path) Then
                MessageBox.Show("File is available")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("File is Not available")
            End If`